# Jenkins multi-configuration project user-defined axis environment variable

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, environment-variables, jenkins

I am trying to set up a multi-configuration project in Jenkins with a single user-defined axis (call it "axis").  The value associated with each configuration would then be used to invoke top-level maven targets in `${axis}/pom.xml`.  The trouble is, I can't find the proper syntax for this, if indeed it does exist (`${axis}`, `$axis`, `$AXIS`, and `${env.axis}` all fail).  I would think it would be shell syntax, which it doesn't seem to be, but regardless it should be either simple or impossible.  Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answers -- I was not able to resolve this issue fast enough, so I went with an entirely different build framework.

Answer (score 1):

`${axis}/pom.xml` should work in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Jenkins installation running on Windows?

For each Custom Axis, an environment variable is created. You can refer to your custom axis using `${axis}` if your server is running Linux, but on Windows you must refer to it as `%axis%`

Comment: The %axis% syntax does indeed work in windows batch command, but it is not resolved when running a Maven build. The axis values are passed to the mvn command as system properties (using the -D flag)

Comment: Wow! just loved it! After spending lot of time figuring that out.. this just made my day

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that OP has solved this in a different way, but for the record the following works in *Hudson* in Windows and Linux. I haven't tried it in *Jenkins*:

The syntax you need for this is simply `$axis/pom.xml`

I defined an axis of `BuildProfile=compile unitTest integrationTest`

And in the Maven 3 configuration (under Advanced properties) a POM file of `$BuildProfile/pom.xml`

The resulting builds gave the following output in the console (edited for brevity):

> [1.7.0_25] $ C:\Users...\bin\mvn.bat clean install -V -B
>   -DBuildProfile=compile -f **compile/pom.xml**
>
> [1.7.0_25] $ C:\Users...\bin\mvn.bat clean install -V -B
>   -DBuildProfile=unitTest -f **unitTest/pom.xml**
>
> [1.7.0_25] $ C:\Users...\bin\mvn.bat clean install -V -B
>   -DBuildProfile=integrationTests -f **integrationTests/pom.xml**

Answer (score 0):

We use a jdk axis and just use the name of the jdk so I think you could just use `axis/pom.xml`